# Why an npm library cannot work with node? How to handle this kind of incompatibility?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tradingview-api

So I'm trying to use two different libraries. The first one is [@pancakeswap-libs/sdk](https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancakeswap-sdk) which requires node to function. The second is lightweight charts which can't run on node (reference https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/issues/557).

My idea was to import the tradingview library through script in an HTML file and create the chart from an external js file while on node I read the HTML doc and print the result while parsing data using the same HTML file but making the data invisible.

I am kinda lost because I don't understand how should I use the tradingview sdks, what server should I use if it doesn't work with node?
Also, do I need to use typescript to use a typescript library?

Comment: Not all npm packages are made for node. npm _doesn't_ stand for node package manager.

Comment: Just to clarify:
1) you want to render the HTML page with chart on the server
2) you then want to parse data from the rendered chart on the server

Comment: I'd like to create a chart based on the data that I collect in node with pancakeswap sdks